# How to make a pdf signature visible (along with validity icons)

Tags: ruby, pdf, digital-signature, visible

Initially the question was about making a pdf signature visible with Ruby. That i can do now with the code below.

My only problem now is with the validity icon. It shows up on [FoxIt Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/), but not on [Acrobat Reader](http://get.adobe.com/uk/reader/) (i'm using XI right now)

This is what I have right now

```
require 'openssl'

begin
  require 'origami'
rescue LoadError
  ORIGAMIDIR = "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\origami-1.2.4\lib"
  $: << ORIGAMIDIR
  require 'origami'
end
include Origami

def draw_signature(name, attr = {})
  load! if @instructions.nil?

  x, y = attr[:x], attr[:y]

  @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('q')
  @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('cm', 1, 0, 0, 1, x, y)
  @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('Do', name)
  @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('Q')
end

def SignPdf(inputF)

    @inputfile = String.new(inputF)
    outputF = @inputfile.insert(inputF.rindex("."),"_signed8")
    certFile = "cert.pem"
    rsakeyFile = "pk.pem"
    passphrase = "mypass"

    key4pem=File.read rsakeyFile
    key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new key4pem, passphrase
    cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read certFile)

    pdf = PDF.read(inputF)
    page = pdf.get_page(1)


#signature image
imageobject = Origami::Graphics::ImageXObject.from_image_file('c:\rails_projects\RecibosOnline\app\assets\images\logo.jpg', 'jpg')
imageobject.Width = 200
imageobject.Height = 141

 #formobject = Origami::Graphics::FormXObject.new
 #formobject.write("Teste")

width = 300
height=141
x=201
y=186

signedby = "My Company"
location = "Portugal"#pdf.signature[pdf.signature.keys[5]]
contact = "mail@mail.com" #pdf.signature[pdf.signature.keys[6]]
reason = "Testing" #pdf.signature[pdf.signature.keys[7]]
date = Time.now

caption="Digitally Signed By: #{signedby}\nContact: #{contact}\nLocation: #{location}\nReason: #{reason}\nDate: #{date} "

n0 = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new
n0.Type=Origami::Name.new("XObject")
n0.BBox = [ 0, 0, 100, 100 ]
n0.Matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
n0.set_indirect(true)
n0.Resources = Resources.new
n0.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("PDF"),Origami::Name.new("Text"),Origami::Name.new("Text"),Origami::Name.new("ImageB"),Origami::Name.new("ImageC"),Origami::Name.new("ImageI")]
n0.draw_stream('% DSBlank')
#n0.write(Origami::Name.new("% DSBlank"))

n2 = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new
n2.Type = Origami::Name.new("XObject")
#n2.Subtype = Origami::Name.new("Form")
n2.Resources = Resources.new
n2.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("Text")]
n2.set_indirect(true)
n2.Matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
n2.BBox = [ 0, 0, width, height ]
n2.write(caption,:x => 40, :y => height-35, :size => 15)
#n2.draw_stream("q 0 0 198 48 re W n BT /Helv 7.645 Tf 0 g 0 40.135 Td (Digitally ) Tj 28.889 0 Td (signed ) Tj 24.652 0 Td (by ) Tj10.198 0 Td (James ) Tj 24.641 0 Td (Pravetz ) Tj-88.38 -9.174 Td (DN: ) Tj 15.29 0 Td (cn=James ) Tj37.18 0 Td (Pravetz, ) Tj 30.165 0 Td (c=CA, ) Tj 23.156 0 Td0 -9.174 Td (Reason: ) Tj 30.599 0 Td (I ) Tj 4.248 0 Td(have ) Tj 18.702 0 Td (reviewed ) Tj 32.719 0 Td(this ) Tj 14.02 0 Td (document ) Tj -100.288 -9.174 Td(Date: ) Tj 20.397 0 Td (2006.06.08 ) Tj 40.386 0 Td(13:39:35 ) Tj 31.883 0 Td (-07'00') Tj ET Q")

#Sets the root dictionary element

frm = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new
frm.set_indirect(true)
#frm.Type = Origami::Name.new("XObject")
#frm.Subtype = Origami::Name.new("Form")
frm.Resources = Resources.new
frm.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("PDF")]
frm.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n0"), n0)
frm.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n2"), n2)
frm.Matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
frm.BBox = [ 0, 0, width, height ]
frm.draw_stream('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /n0 Do Q')
frm.draw_stream('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /n2 Do Q')




xo17 = Annotation::Widget::Signature.new
#xo17 = Annotation::Widget::Signature.new
xo17.Rect = Rectangle[ llx: x, lly: y, urx: x+width, ury: y+height ]
#xo17.Resources = Resources.new
#xo17.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("FRM"), frm)
xo17.F = Annotation::Flags::PRINT #sets the print mode on
xo17.H = Annotation::Widget::Highlight::INVERT

streamN = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new #.setFilter(:FlateDecode)
streamN.set_indirect(true)
streamN.BBox = [ 0, 0, width, height ]
streamN.Resources = Resources.new
streamN.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("PDF")]
streamN.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("FRM"), frm)
streamN.Subtype = nil
#cs = ContentStream.new('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /FRM Do Q',streamN)
streamN.draw_stream('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /FRM Do Q')
#streamN.draw_image(Origami::Name.new("FRM"),{x:x,y:y})
#streamN.write(caption,:x => 40, :y => height-35, :size => 15)
xo17.set_normal_appearance(streamN)

# page.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("FRM"),frm)
# page.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n0"),n0)
# page.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n2"),n2)

page.add_annot(xo17)    

# Sign the PDF with the specified keys
pdf.sign(cert, key, 
  :method => 'adbe.pkcs7.sha1',
  :annotation => xo17, 
  :location => location, 
  :contact => contact, 
  :reason => reason
)

# Save the resulting file
pdf.save(outputF)


end
SignPdf("Sample.pdf")
```

**EDIT 2**

Following mkl intervention, i went a little further into the source...

I noticed the [xobject.rb](http://code.google.com/p/origami-pdf/source/browse/lib/origami/graphics/xobject.rb) file, with the following code for drawing an image

```
def draw_image(name, attr = {})
      load! if @instructions.nil?

      x, y = attr[:x], attr[:y]

      @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('q')
      @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('cm', 300, 0, 0, 300, x, y)
      @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('Do', name)
      @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('Q')
end
```

I have then created the method below on that same file

```
def draw_stream(name)
      load! if @instructions.nil?

      @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new(name)
end
```

which allows me to control the stream from its input.

I also went to [ISO32000:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), and iterated a bit thorugh my code, but got nowhere further.

Here is my currently generated [pdf file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6SE5r_sflg7RE5OMHlaQ2h3VXM/edit?usp=sharing) , and the part of it that relates to signatures:

```
16 0 obj
<<
    /Rect [ 201 186 501 327 ]
    /F 4
    /H /I
    /AP <<
        /N 18 0 R
    >>
    /P 1 0 R
    /V 17 0 R
    /T (undef28504)
    /Subtype /Widget
    /FT /Sig
    /DA (/F1 10 Tf 0 g)
>>
endobj
17 0 obj
<<
    /Type /Sig
    /SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.sha1
    /Reason <54657374696E67>
    /Prop_Build <<
        /Filter <<
            /Name /Adobe.PPKMS
            /R 131101
            /Date (2013-04-03 14:18:41 +0100)
        >>
        /SigQ <<
            /Preview false
            /R 131101
        >>
        /PubSec <<
            /NonEFontNoWarn false
            /Date (2013-04-03 14:18:41 +0100)
            /R 131101
        >>
        /App <<
            /TrustedMode false
            /OS [ /Win ]
            /R 458752
            /Name /Exchange-Pro
        >>
    >>
    /M (D:20130403131841Z00'00)
    /Location <506F72747567616C>
    /Filter /Adobe.PPKMS
    /Contents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
    /ContactInfo <6D61696C406D61696C2E636F6D>
    /ByteRange [ 0 12880 17078 2366 ]
>>
endobj
18 0 obj
<<
    /BBox [ 0 0 300 141 ]
    /Resources <<
        /ProcSet [ /PDF ]
        /XObject <<
            /FRM 19 0 R
        >>
        /Font <<
            /F1 <<
                /Type /Font
                /Subtype /Type1
                /BaseFont /Helvetica
                /Name /F1
            >>
        >>
    >>
    /Length 27
    /Subtype /Form
>>stream
q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /FRM Do Q

endstream
endobj
19 0 obj
<<
    /Resources <<
        /ProcSet [ /PDF ]
        /XObject <<
            /n0 20 0 R
            /n2 21 0 R
        >>
        /Font <<
            /F1 <<
                /Type /Font
                /Subtype /Type1
                /BaseFont /Helvetica
                /Name /F1
            >>
        >>
    >>
    /Matrix [ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ]
    /BBox [ 0 0 300 141 ]
    /Length 52
    /Subtype /Form
>>stream
q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /n0 Do Q
q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /n2 Do Q

endstream
endobj
20 0 obj
<<
    /Type /XObject
    /BBox [ 0 0 100 100 ]
    /Matrix [ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ]
    /Resources <<
        /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]
        /Font <<
            /F1 <<
                /Type /Font
                /Subtype /Type1
                /BaseFont /Helvetica
                /Name /F1
            >>
        >>
    >>
    /Length 10
    /Subtype /Form
>>stream
% DSBlank

endstream
endobj
21 0 obj
<<
    /Type /XObject
    /Resources <<
        /ProcSet [ /Text ]
        /Font <<
            /F1 <<
                /Type /Font
                /Subtype /Type1
                /BaseFont /Helvetica
                /Name /F1
            >>
        >>
    >>
    /Matrix [ 1 0 0 1 0 0 ]
    /BBox [ 0 0 300 141 ]
    /Length 176
    /Subtype /Form
>>stream
BT
/F1 15 Tf
40 106 Td
20 TL
(Digitally Signed By: My Company) Tj
(Contact: mail@mail.com) '
(Location: Portugal) '
(Reason: Testing) '
(Date: 2013-04-03 14:18:41 +0100 ) '
ET

endstream
endobj
22 0 obj
<<
    /Fields [ 16 0 R ]
    /SigFlags 3
>>
endobj
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your *workaround, that uses set_normal_appearance method, but still* makes you *missing the validation image* uses a regular appearance stream. Signature appearance streams with special behavior in Adobe Reader use a special format, cf. [Digital Signature Appearances](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PPKAppearances.pdf). Furthermore your requirement that *the content should be read from the document properties, and not loaded before save* cannot be fulfilled as the signature appearance stream is part of the signed PDF content and, thus, created before saving.

Comment: Thank you for the reference @mkl . Loading the contents before save is not a strict requirement, since it won't "hurt" setting the date by hand (since this is an automatic process), and the other fields are known prior to the document saving.
Do you have any idea how can i implement a Digital Signature appearance with ruby?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have some knowledge concerning PDF and integrated PDF signatures in particular but hardly any concerning ruby.

Comment: Well, I will submerge onto it. If I have a BBox i might have some of those signature methods too.

Comment: @mkl, if I gave you a signed pdf file, would you be able to understand what is missing from that file, for Adobe to show the Check/Question/Error Mark? What layer am I currently working on? top-level? N0 ? N2 ?

Comment: I just looked at your PDF. First: The syntax in the appearance stream is wront: there is `(/FRM) Do`, `(/n0) Do`, and `(/n2) Do`. To be syntactically correct (**Do** expects a name as operand, not a string) those command would have to be `/FRM Do`, `/n0 Do`, and `/n2 Do`. Then there must be XObject resources defined for the appearance stream with those names. And even after fixing these details, the structure differs from that explained in the mentioned Adobe documentation: ...

Comment: ... And even after fixing these details, the structure differs from that explained in the mentioned Adobe documentation: There the **/N** appearance stream references the **/FRM** XObject which in turn references **/n0** and **/n2** XObjects which in turn contain actually displayed data. Your **/N** appearance stream references (syntactically incorrectly) **/FRM**, **/n0**, and **/n2** XObjects and also contains data to display. That being said I'm not sure anyways whether current Adobe Reader versions still apply the decorations on page or only in the ribbon and the signature panel.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27357/discussion-between-mrwater-and-mkl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, a man just need to know how to actually understand what he reads over and over again...

The ppkappearances file had it all there. I didn't even went as far as I expected i would have with complying with the dictionary structure they recommend there.
I just needed to add the n1 and n3 layers, and the stream content could even be just "% DS Blank". the question mark string stream you find was the one i took from `PdfSignatureAppearance.cs` file from [iText](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php) solution. If I use that one Foxit Reader presents the question mark (even if the signature is valid). For Adobe it doesn't matter i use that or `DSBlank`.

```
require 'openssl'

begin
  require 'origami'
rescue LoadError
  ORIGAMIDIR = "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\origami-1.2.4\lib"
  $: << ORIGAMIDIR
  require 'origami'
end
include Origami

def draw_signature(name, attr = {})
  load! if @instructions.nil?

  x, y = attr[:x], attr[:y]

  @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('q')
  @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('cm', 1, 0, 0, 1, x, y)
  @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('Do', name)
  @instructions << PDF::Instruction.new('Q')
end

def SignPdf(inputF)

    @inputfile = String.new(inputF)
    outputF = @inputfile.insert(inputF.rindex("."),"_signed8")
    certFile = "cert.pem"
    rsakeyFile = "pk.pem"
    passphrase = "mypass"

    key4pem=File.read rsakeyFile
    key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new key4pem, passphrase
    cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read certFile)

    pdf = PDF.read(inputF)
    page = pdf.get_page(1)


#signature image
imageobject = Origami::Graphics::ImageXObject.from_image_file('c:\rails_projects\RecibosOnline\app\assets\images\logo.jpg', 'jpg')
imageobject.Width = 200
imageobject.Height = 141

 #formobject = Origami::Graphics::FormXObject.new
 #formobject.write("Teste")

width = 300
height=141
x=201
y=186

signedby = "My Company"
location = "Portugal"#pdf.signature[pdf.signature.keys[5]]
contact = "mail@mail.com" #pdf.signature[pdf.signature.keys[6]]
reason = "Testing" #pdf.signature[pdf.signature.keys[7]]
date = Time.now

caption="Digitally Signed By: #{signedby}\nContact: #{contact}\nLocation: #{location}\nReason: #{reason}\nDate: #{date} "

    #DSBlankstream= "% DSBLank"

    questionMark = "% DSUnknown\n" +
            "q\n" +
            "1 G\n" +
            "1 g\n" +
            "0.1 0 0 0.1 9 0 cm\n" +
            "0 J 0 j 4 M []0 d\n" +
            "1 i \n" +
            "0 g\n" +
            "313 292 m\n" +
            "313 404 325 453 432 529 c\n" +
            "478 561 504 597 504 645 c\n" +
            "504 736 440 760 391 760 c\n" +
            "286 760 271 681 265 626 c\n" +
            "265 625 l\n" +
            "100 625 l\n" +
            "100 828 253 898 381 898 c\n" +
            "451 898 679 878 679 650 c\n" +
            "679 555 628 499 538 435 c\n" +
            "488 399 467 376 467 292 c\n" +
            "313 292 l\n" +
            "h\n" +
            "308 214 170 -164 re\n" +
            "f\n" +
            "0.44 G\n" +
            "1.2 w\n" +
            "1 1 0.4 rg\n" +
            "287 318 m\n" +
            "287 430 299 479 406 555 c\n" +
            "451 587 478 623 478 671 c\n" +
            "478 762 414 786 365 786 c\n" +
            "260 786 245 707 239 652 c\n" +
            "239 651 l\n" +
            "74 651 l\n" +
            "74 854 227 924 355 924 c\n" +
            "425 924 653 904 653 676 c\n" +
            "653 581 602 525 512 461 c\n" +
            "462 425 441 402 441 318 c\n" +
            "287 318 l\n" +
            "h\n" +
            "282 240 170 -164 re\n" +
            "B\n" +
            "Q\n";

    n0 = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new
    n0.Type=Origami::Name.new("XObject")
    n0.BBox = [ 0, 0, 100, 100 ]
    n0.Matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
    n0.set_indirect(true)
    n0.Resources = Resources.new
    n0.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("PDF"),Origami::Name.new("Text"),Origami::Name.new("Text"),Origami::Name.new("ImageB"),Origami::Name.new("ImageC"),Origami::Name.new("ImageI")]
    n0.draw_stream('% DSBlank')
    #n0.write(Origami::Name.new("% DSBlank"))


    n1 = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new
    n1.Type=Origami::Name.new("XObject")
    n1.BBox = [ 0, 0, 100, 100 ]
    n1.Matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
    n1.set_indirect(true)
    n1.Resources = Resources.new
    n1.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("PDF"),Origami::Name.new("Text"),Origami::Name.new("Text"),Origami::Name.new("ImageB"),Origami::Name.new("ImageC"),Origami::Name.new("ImageI")]
    n1.draw_stream('% DSBlank')

    n3 = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new
    n3.Type=Origami::Name.new("XObject")
    n3.BBox = [ 0, 0, 100, 100 ]
    n3.Matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
    n3.set_indirect(true)
    n3.Resources = Resources.new
    n3.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("PDF"),Origami::Name.new("Text"),Origami::Name.new("Text"),Origami::Name.new("ImageB"),Origami::Name.new("ImageC"),Origami::Name.new("ImageI")]
    n3.draw_stream('% DSBlank')

    n2 = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new
    n2.Type = Origami::Name.new("XObject")
    #n2.Subtype = Origami::Name.new("Form")
    n2.Resources = Resources.new
    n2.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("Text")]
    n2.set_indirect(true)
    n2.Matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
    n2.BBox = [ 0, 0, width, height ]
    n2.write(caption,:x => 40, :y => height-35, :size => 15)
    #n2.draw_stream("q 0 0 198 48 re W n BT /Helv 7.645 Tf 0 g 0 40.135 Td (Digitally ) Tj 28.889 0 Td (signed ) Tj 24.652 0 Td (by ) Tj10.198 0 Td (James ) Tj 24.641 0 Td (Pravetz ) Tj-88.38 -9.174 Td (DN: ) Tj 15.29 0 Td (cn=James ) Tj37.18 0 Td (Pravetz, ) Tj 30.165 0 Td (c=CA, ) Tj 23.156 0 Td0 -9.174 Td (Reason: ) Tj 30.599 0 Td (I ) Tj 4.248 0 Td(have ) Tj 18.702 0 Td (reviewed ) Tj 32.719 0 Td(this ) Tj 14.02 0 Td (document ) Tj -100.288 -9.174 Td(Date: ) Tj 20.397 0 Td (2006.06.08 ) Tj 40.386 0 Td(13:39:35 ) Tj 31.883 0 Td (-07'00') Tj ET Q")

##Sets the root dictionary element

    frm = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new
    frm.set_indirect(true)
    #frm.Type = Origami::Name.new("XObject")
    #frm.Subtype = Origami::Name.new("Form")
    frm.Resources = Resources.new
    frm.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("PDF")]
    frm.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n0"), n0)
    frm.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n1"), n1)
    frm.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n2"), n2)
    frm.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n3"), n3)
    frm.Matrix = [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
    frm.BBox = [ 0, 0, width, height ]
    frm.draw_stream('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /n0 Do Q')
    frm.draw_stream('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /n1 Do Q')
    frm.draw_stream('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /n2 Do Q')
    frm.draw_stream('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /n3 Do Q')


    xo17 = Annotation::Widget::Signature.new
    #xo17 = Annotation::Widget::Signature.new
    xo17.Rect = Rectangle[ llx: x, lly: y, urx: x+width, ury: y+height ]
    #xo17.Resources = Resources.new
    #xo17.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("FRM"), frm)
    xo17.F = Annotation::Flags::PRINT #sets the print mode on
    xo17.H = Annotation::Widget::Highlight::INVERT

    streamN = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new #.setFilter(:FlateDecode)
    streamN.set_indirect(true)
    streamN.BBox = [ 0, 0, width, height ]
    streamN.Resources = Resources.new
    streamN.Resources.ProcSet = [Origami::Name.new("PDF")]
    streamN.Resources.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("FRM"), frm)
    streamN.Subtype = nil
    #cs = ContentStream.new('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /FRM Do Q',streamN)
    streamN.draw_stream('q 1 0 0 1 0 0 cm /FRM Do Q')
    #streamN.draw_image(Origami::Name.new("FRM"),{x:x,y:y})
    #streamN.write(caption,:x => 40, :y => height-35, :size => 15)
    xo17.set_normal_appearance(streamN)

    # page.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("FRM"),frm)
    # page.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n0"),n0)
    # page.add_xobject(Origami::Name.new("n2"),n2)

    page.add_annot(xo17)    

    # Sign the PDF with the specified keys
    pdf.sign(cert, key, 
      :method => 'adbe.pkcs7.sha1',
      :annotation => xo17, 
      :location => location, 
      :contact => contact, 
      :reason => reason
    )

    # Save the resulting file
    pdf.save(outputF)


end

SignPdf("Sample.pdf")
```

What a fight!

I feel like saying :

In the end, the winners are the ones that you will find standing in the middle of the battle field. Sadly looking around them into the battle field, and wondering why it had to be like that. Only if they knew how to read...then nothing of that would have happened. At the same time though, if it wouldn't have happened, they wouldn't know they didn't know how to read with the right focus.